# equicontinuous on spherical metric

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have $f_n(Z)=z^n$, question is find all $a \in \bar{\mathbb{C}}$ such that $f_n$ is equicontinuous.

If $\epsilon > 0$ and $|z-a| < \epsilon$, then $d(f_n(z), f_n(z'))= \frac{2|z^n-a^n|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2n}} \sqrt{1+|a|^{2n}}}$.

What should I do after that?

Comment: $n\in \mathbb{N}$, or $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

I imagine $f$ as a map of sphere onto itself which fixes both poles $0,\infty$, wraps equator around itself $n$ times and pushes all non-equatorial points toward the nearer pole. This suggests the answer: equicontinuity holds as long as $a$ is not on the equator.

For a formal proof, begin by considering $|a|<1$. Let $r=(1+|a|)/2 $. Given $\epsilon>0$, you can find $N$ such that $f_n(\{z:|z|<r\})\subset \{w:|w|<\epsilon/2\}$ for all $n\ge N$. The rest are finitely many functions $f_1,\dots,f_{N-1}$;   you can pick $\delta>0$ that works for the given $\epsilon$ and for all $n=1,\dots,N-1$. This proves equicontinuity at $a$.

The case $|a|>1$ is exactly the same, because of the spherical isometry $z\mapsto z^{-1}$.

If $|a|=1$, then any neighborhood  of $a$ will contain a point $b$ such that $|f_n(b)|<1/2$ for some $n$; no equicontinuity.